# making a subdirectory of static dir a python module?

Tags: django, static, module

I'm using a python file as a data (because it is easier to use constant defined in python file this way).

Since my other data files are organized under a static directory, I'd like to make those data directories as a python module (putting `__init__.py`) so that I can use data.py under those directories as a python module.

Would you advise against it?

Comment: s/module/package/. And yes, I would not place python source code in the static dir. What's your real use case ? (I mean, who uses these "data" and whatfor ?)

Comment: imgs, data htmls are currently stored in static dir. I wanted to store json-like data (product related) which will be updated and fed into DB along with other data in static dir. If it's not a good idea to place __init__.py in the static dir, I would just use json and getattr(string) to get constants.

Answer (score 0):

According to your last comment, you probably want to use json fixtures : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-fixtures

Comment: thanks for input, but I made management command to work with the json file. fixture doesn't seem to handle data-update scenario well. I suppose that's why they call 'initial-data-with-fixtures'.